# Unable to drag directed graph

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, next.js, next.js13

The following is a component in `NextJS` and I am using version `13.3.1`

using the experimental `app` folder.

I am trying to use the dependency `react-d3-graph` to draw a directed graph.

It does render as expected. But the moment I try to click and `drag` a node, node doesn't move.

And getting the error:

> caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'undefined')
> at SVGGElement.eval (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/react-d3-graph/lib/components/graph/Graph.js:273:24)
> at Dispatch.call (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/d3-dispatch/src/dispatch.js:58:72)
> at Object.gesture [as mouse] (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/d3-drag/src/drag.js:159:16)
> at mousemoved (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/d3-drag/src/drag.js:82:14)
> at eval (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/d3-selection/src/selection/on.js:7:14)

Why?

P.S: I have tried this on a basic react app and same error.

I see a very similar implementation [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/d3-graph-3go4d?file=/package.json:137-144).

Even if I copy over the exact code from [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/d3-graph-3go4d?file=/package.json:137-144) example, I still get same error.

This example has additional dependencies like `d3-drag` which I don't have but tried adding anyway.

Same error outcome.

This is my nextjs config.

```
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
    esmExternals: 'loose',
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.17",
    "@types/node": "18.16.3",
    "@types/react": "18.2.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.1",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",

    // added these just to check after I got errors and same outcome
    "d3": "^7.8.4",
    "d3-drag": "^3.0.0",
    "d3-force": "^3.0.0",
    "d3-shape": "^3.2.0",
    "d3-zoom": "^3.0.0",


    "eslint": "8.39.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.3.1",
    "neo4j-driver": "^5.7.0",
    "next": "13.3.1",
    "postcss": "8.4.23",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-d3-graph": "^2.6.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2",
    "typescript": "5.0.4",
    "zustand": "^4.3.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/d3": "^7.4.0",
    "@types/react-d3-graph": "^2.6.3"
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Please advice. Thanks.

This is the component

```
'use client'
import React from 'react';
import { Graph } from 'react-d3-graph';

const Chart = () => {

  const data = {
    nodes: [
      { id: 'Za', label: 'Za', gender: 'Male' },
      { id: 'Th', label: 'Th', gender: 'Female' },
      { id: 'Al', label: 'Al', gender: 'Female' },
      { id: 'Kr', label: 'Kr', gender: 'Male' },
      { id: 'Te', label: 'Te', gender: 'Female' },
    ],
    links: [
      { source: 'Za', target: 'Th', label: 'A_WITH' },
      { source: 'Za', target: 'Al', label: 'A_WITH' },
      { source: 'Kr', target: 'Za', label: 'B_OF' },
      { source: 'Te', target: 'Za', label: 'A_OF' },
    ],
  };

  const config = {
    nodeHighlightBehavior: true,
    node: {
      color: "lightgreen",
      size: 120,
      labelProperty: "id",
      highlightStrokeColor: "blue",
      draggable: true, // make the nodes draggable
    },
    link: {
      type: "CURVE_SMOOTH",
      highlightColor: "lightblue",
    },
    // add the drag event handler
    d3: {
      alphaTarget: 0.05,
      gravity: -100,
      linkLength: 100,
      linkStrength: 1,
      disableLinkForce: false,
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      nodesDraggable: true, // enable node dragging
      onDragStart: (node) => {
        // update the state of the node being dragged
        console.log("dragging started", node);
      },
      onDrag: (node, x, y) => {
        // update the state of the node as it is being dragged
        console.log("dragging", node, x, y);
      },
      onDragEnd: (node) => {
        // update the state of the node after it has been dragged
        console.log("dragging ended", node);
      },
    },
  };


  const onClickNode = (nodeId: string) => {
    // this is working fine. Issue is only on dragging
    const node = data.nodes.find((n) => n.id === nodeId);
    window.alert(`Clicked node ${node?.label}`);
  };


  return (
    <Graph
      id="graph-id"
      data={data}
      config={config}
      onClickNode={onClickNode}
    />
  );
};

export default Chart;
```